# Powershell opens System Control Panel instead of executing code

Tags: windows, powershell, controls, system, panel

First of all, I'm not trolling, this is happening, and I have NO idea why. I did this tiny script to test variable scopes:

```
$a = 1

Main

Function Main {
    echo $a
}
```

Now, I'm executing it.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

PS C:\Users\me> & 'C:\backup\variable scopes.ps1'
PS C:\Users\me>
```

And the only thing that happens is, ***the windows control panel mouse configuration window opens***, allowing me to adjust speed, double click timout and so on.

I'm completely speechless :D No idea if anyone else can get this minimal example to work for him, but please, enlighten me if you can.

This happens every time, I have tried restarting the power shell console, and driven by sheer desperation, I have even added the necessary keyword global in front of the variable to modify the scope, but even then there is no output and the thing still opens up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your function to something else. main is the name for the Mouse control panel applet. It's using that instead of your function.

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed the same thing, and Google brought me here when I started looking.

I've got a script I named "main.ps1", and when I tried to run it a minute ago, I forgot to surround it with "./" and ".ps1" and found myself looking at the mouse control panel applet.

Get-command and Get-Alias don't list anything called "main"

Get-help doesn't return any results for "main" or "about_main".

I tried running "main" from a regular command prompt, but there's nothing on the DOS side named "main", so it's got to be something that Powershell is doing.

It's definitely strange behavior.  Interesting...

EDIT: just realized that the Mouse control panel is named main.cpl .   So that's where it's coming from.